# array_diff not always correct

Tags: php, arrays, diff

I show my example of diff between values in arrays, sometimes doesn't work corectly.

```
$fields = array(
    '1x1' => 'k',
    '1x2' => 'B',
    '1x3' => 'c',
    '2x1' => 'd',
    '2x2' => 'x',
    '2x3' => 'Y',
    '3x1' => 'b',
    '3x2' => 'e',
    '3x3' => 'f'
);

print_r($fields);

$answer = array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'x',
    'y',
    'z',
    'e',
    'f'
);

print_r($answer);

echo '<hr />DIFF:<br />';

print_r(array_diff($fields, $answer));

?>
```

Results is:

```
(
    [1x1] => k
    [1x2] => B
    [2x3] => Y
)
```

But should be:

```
(
    [1x1] => k
    [1x2] => B
    [2x3] => Y
    [3x1] => b
)
```

Why for PHP `b` is equal with `z`?
How to repair this?

Comment: The order does not matter for `array_diff()`. It is all about the values and if they are in the other array or not. It also does not matter if a value is 2 or 3 times in the array, if it just exists once that is enough.

Comment: array_diff Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working correct. According to [`array_diff()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

> **array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )**
>
> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Another important info from documentation:

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

So in `$answers` array there are no `k, B, Y` elements of `$fields` array.

Comment: hi bro, array_diff() does not returns correct output everytime

Comment: @rajanasekhar What do you mean? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

The method isn't wrong, compare the 2 lists, they both contain `b`

Answer (score 0):

see you put 'b' into both  the $answer and the $fields array .

so that's why it gives u such output .